# How to make strings upper case in python

Tags: python

I have been looking around for an answer to this and what I could find was you use the `.upper()` command but this doesn't seem to work,

Example,

```
 >>> x = a
 >>>x.upper()
 >>>print (x)
```

But what it displays is just the original.

Comment: you have to assign to a new variable: `x=x.upper()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct way to do it is

```
x = x.upper()
```

Python strings are immutable, so `str.upper()` returns the result instead of changing the string in place (as do all other string manipulation functions).

Answer (score 0):

`x.upper()` does not modify `x`; it just computes the new string, which you'd see if you printed `x.upper()`.  To retain that value, you could assign it back to `x`.